# How to run jar file migrations with flyway spring

Tags: java, spring, flyway

TL:DR How do you run jar files as deltas using spring flyway.

Some background to the problem i encountered.

When running a flyway java delta for example the following:

```
public class V3__0001 implements SpringJdbcMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception {
        List<NewCustomerEntity> newCustomerEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CustomerEntity customer : findAll(jdbcTemplate)){
          NewCustomerEntity c = new NewCustomerEntity();                            
          c.setDate(SomeUtilityTool.transformDate(customer.getDate()));
          newCustomerEntityList.add(c);
        }
        insertAll(newCustomerEntityList);
    }

    private void insertAll(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,List<NewCustomerEntity> newEntities){
        // INSERT STATEMENT
    }

    private List<Customer> findAll(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";
        List<CustomerEntity> customers  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
                                                          new BeanPropertyRowMapper(CustomerEntity.class));
        return customers;
    }
}
```

It takes a list of customers, does something with it using a utility tool accessible in the java environment, for example it can be a maven or gradle dependency.

You create your App-1.1 and run it.

Later when you write the next database migration in java. You want to upgrade SomeUtilityTool from a 1.X to a 2.X, lets say this changes the output of the transformDate function in the example.

Now when someone that uses App-1.0 and upgrades to App-1.2 It does not run the same delta as the one that upgraded from App-1.0 to App-1.1.

My conclusion is that all dependencies should probably have its own module that create an jar artifact. This jar artifact ensures by encapsulating all dependencies that change in a dependency later on will not affect how previous delta was run.

The question is it possible to get spring flyway to pick up and run the jarfile?